# ContourPlot3D for a 3D vector contour plot

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

The procedure [`ContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ContourPlot3D.html) allows plotting the contour lines of the components of a 3D-vector. The problem is I don't know how to give the contour planes of each individual component its own colour. To be more specific: green for the X-component, yellow for the Y and red for the Z-component contour planes.

```
Clear["Global'*"];
B[x_, y_, z_, a_, b_, c_, Br_] :=
  (e := {0, 0, 0};
   Sum[s = x - a (-1)^i; 
    Sum[t = y - b (-1)^j; 
     Sum[u = z - c (-1)^k; r = Sqrt[s^2 + t^2 + u^2]; 
      e = e + (-1)^(i + j + k) {Log[r - t], Log[r - s], 
          ArcTan[(s t)/(r u)]};
      , {k, 0, 1}], {j, 0, 1}]  , {i, 0, 1}];
   Return[e Br/(4 Pi)]);
a = 0.0456/2; b = a; c := 0.0175; Br := 1.4;

ContourPlot3D[
 B[x, y, z, a, b, c, Br], {x, -2 a, 2 a}, {y, -2 a, 2 a}, {z, 0, 4 c},
  Contours -> 21, PlotLabel -> "Field cuboidal magnet", 
 RegionFunction -> (! (#1 > 0 && #2 < 0 && #3 > 0) && ! (#1^2 < 
         a^2 && #2^2 < b^2 && #3^2 < c^2) &), 
 ContourStyle -> 
  Table[Directive[Opacity[0.3], ColorData["BrightBands"][f], 
    Specularity[White, 60]], {f, -0.5, 0.5, 0.05}], PlotPoints -> 16, 
 MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Hi! and welcome to Mma.SE. You can format code with the `{}` button above the edit window.  Folks will appreciate it, if you do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [Kuba's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) comment, I realize that the plot was not doing what I thought it was.  Here is a fixed version.  Plot each component and combine them.  It might seem inefficient, but it's over 15 times faster.

```
Show@MapThread[
  ContourPlot3D[#1,
    {x, -2 a, 2 a}, {y, -2 a, 2 a}, {z, 0, 4 c},
    Contours -> 21, PlotLabel -> "Field cuboidal magnet", 
    RegionFunction -> (! (#1 > 0 && #2 < 0 && #3 > 0) && ! (#1^2 < 
            a^2 && #2^2 < b^2 && #3^2 < c^2) &), 
    ContourStyle -> 
     Directive[Opacity[0.5], #2, Specularity[White, 60]],
    PlotPoints -> 16, MaxRecursion -> 0, Mesh -> False, 
    Lighting -> "Neutral"] &,
  {B[x, y, z, a, b, c, Br], {Green, Yellow, Red}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It might be that the OP want's also to scale each like he did in the example. I've thought that something like `Table[Blend[{color, White}, int], {color, {Green, Yellow, Red}}, {int, 0, 1, 1/20}]` will work but it seems it does not.

Comment: @Kuba  Possibly, but the image is rather overcrowded with information as it is.  Thanks for the comment.  It made realize I made a mistake. :)

Comment: Thanks, It is exactly what I had in mind. Yes, overcrowded, but I think it will set a new line in presenting the results of solving Maxwell equations in lectures and books. Visualise the field is what engineers need.